# Cron not working in magento 1

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I have Magento 1 store up and running, But I can see the cron job is not working. I can't see any entry in the cron_schedule table. Also when I execute cron.php or cron.sh manually from the command line then also I am not seeing any entries in the cron table and those are not getting added in the cron table.

What could be the reason for this, Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: When you try to run it manually, have you check the magento log file?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this [Magento 1 How Cron Jobs Works In Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252628/magento-1-how-cron-jobs-works-in-magento) ? if not you may get help from this